# Что тут происходит?

Tags: java, хеширование, битовые-операции, hashcode

```
public static int keyHashCode(long key) {
    key = (~key) + (key << 18); // key = (key << 18) - key - 1;
    key = key ^ (key >>> 31);
    key = key * 21;             // key = (key + (key << 2)) + (key << 4);
    key = key ^ (key >>> 11);
    key = key + (key << 6);
    key = key ^ (key >>> 22);
    return (int)key;
}
```

Comment: Что написали, то и происходит. А какова была первоначальная  цель?

Comment: Судя по названию, всего лишь вычисление хэша :) Или вопрос, какой именно алгоритм хэширования?

Comment: Побитовые операции - отражение, сдвиг, XOR. Цель манипуляций видимо известна автору, сразу так не догадаешся, вообще судя по названию метода получения хэша из ключа. Если не понятны сами операторы, смотрите, например, [эту статью](http://www.helloworld.ru/texts/comp/lang/java/java/05.htm)

Comment: @Алексей, а зачем вы откатили к прошлой версии? Вроде бы метки были вполне подходящие.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а ведь уведомление и мне пришло) и я сижу не понимаю что я натворил

Answer (score 5):

Предположу, что автору неизвестны сами побитовые операции (иначе стоит пояснить вопрос).

Достаточно детализированный гайд есть на [вики ИТМО](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Но если коротко:

`~a` — побитовое НЕ. Инвертируется каждый бит числа.

`a << b` — сдвиг влево. Берется двоичное представление числа `a`, все его биты сдвигаются на `b` влево и справа дописывается `b` нулей.

`a >> b` — сдвиг вправо. Работает аналогично сдвигу влево, но с оговоркой. Если старший бит числа — единица, то слева будут добавляться единицы, чтобы сохранить знак числа. Это связано с тем, что [старший бит отрицательных чисел — единица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)).

`a >>> b` — беззнаковый сдвиг вправо. В отличие от обычного сдвига вправо, всегда дописывает нулевые биты слева. Можно заметить, что именно он используется вместо сдвига вправо в этой функции.

`a ^ b` — побитовое исключающее ИЛИ.

---

Существуют и стандартные способы получить хэш из `long`.

- В Java 8 есть [Long.hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#hashCode-long-).
- В Guava есть [аналогичная](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Longs.html#hashCode-long-).